# What does mean by "running selenium tests are in headless mode " in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone explain what is running selenium tests in headless mode in jenkins?

Comment: It means they're not attached to a specific browser, and are probably running against something like a HtmlUnit driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment it's a way of running tests in a browser that doesn't have a GUI attached to it

> What is a headless browser? (Quoted from [ToolsQA](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/headless-browser-testing-selenium-webdriver/))
>
> Headless browser is a term used to define browser simulation programs
>   which do not have a GUI. These programs behave just like a browser but
>   don’t show any GUI. Famous ones are HtmlUnit and the NodeJs headless
>   browsers. There are a good number of more browsers too.
>
> What is the use of Headless browsers?
>
> Headless browsers are typically used in following situations
>
> 1. You have a central build tool which does not have any browser installed on it. So to do the basic level of sanity tests after every
>      build you may use the headless browser to run your tests.
> 2. You want to write a crawler program that goes through different pages and collects data, headless browser will be your choice. Because
>      you really don’t care about opening a browser. All you need is to
>      access the webpages.
> 3. You would like to simulate multiple browser versions on the same machine. In that case you would want to use a headless browser,
>      because most of them support simulation of different versions of
>      browsers. We will come to this point soon.
>
> Things to pay attention to before using headless browser
>
> Headless browsers are simulation programs, they are not your real
>   browsers. Most of these headless browsers have evolved enough to
>   simulate, to a pretty close approximation, like a real browser. Still
>   you would not want to run all your tests in a headless browser.
>   JavaScript is one area where you would want to be really careful
>   before using a Headless browser. JavaScript are implemented
>   differently by different browsers. Although JavaScript is a standard
>   but each browser has its own little differences in the way that they
>   have implemented JavaScript. This is also true in case of headless
>   browsers also. For example HtmlUnit headless browser uses the Rihno
>   JavaScript engine which not being used by any other browser.